# CloudBees Runtime Classpath

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, cloudbees, paas

I just read the CloudBees whitepaper ["CloudBees Advantages: A Guide for Java Developers"](http://pages.cloudbees.com/CloudBees-Advantages-Guide-Java-Developers.html). In it there is a sentence that reads:

> The database is simply available as a JNDI resource as soon as it is deployed – there is no need to chase down JDBC drivers, connection strings and configure JNDI.

So I *assume* that means I don't need to include a MySQL JDBC driver in my WAR's `WEB-INF/lib` directory, as apparently CloudBees provides it to the classpath at run time, yes.

This also prompts a few other questions:

1. What version of the MySQL JDBC driver (and which type) is provided by CloudBees?
2. Does the same apply for the Cloudant CouchDB service, or drivers/dependencies used by other service partners?
3. Are there any other libs that CloudBees makes available to the runtime classpath for its clients?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Cloudbees currently provided version 5.1.16 of the MySQL JDBC driver with the jboss stack, and 5.1.15 with tomcat6 and any other stacks. Unfortunately, this information isn't documented anywhere publicly. [Caleb Tennis](https://twitter.com/ctennis), one of their developers, informed me of this via their IRC channel, #cloudbees.

Regarding Cloudant, it's more or less just CouchDB, so to connect you can use [these libraries](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java) from the CouchDB wiki.

Alternatively, CouchDB amounts to a REST API, so it might be easier to use a straight HTTP library to make requests and parse responses. Whatever you're most comfortable with, really :D

As for what other libraries Cloudbees makes available to the runtime path, more from Caleb Tennis:

> Other than mysql, there are no "guaranteed" runtime libraries - you will need to put them into your war or other package for deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback regarding CouchDB/Cloudant @garbados (+1) - but still waiting for answers on the other questions.

Comment: Updated. Does that all answer your question?